# The condition $\lambda({x; |f(x)|>a})< \infty$ for any $a>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

In class we discussed the Sobolev inequality and in its statement we had that some function $f$ has to satisfy $\lambda( \{ x; |f(x)|>a \})< \infty$ for any $a>0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Now, I started wondering how strong this condition is. So I started thinking which kind of functions would satisfy this condition. In particular, I am looking for (very large) classes of functions satisfying this.

Clearly, compactly supported functions fulfill this requirement. Also functions having a decay similar to the one of Schwartz functions fulfill this property.

But what about $L^p$ functions or even larger classes?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions in $L^p$ (for $p \in \left[ 1,\infty \right)$) will satisfy this property: for any $f \in L^p \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) $ and for any $\alpha > 0$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {|f|}^{p} \geqslant \int_{\lbrace{|f|}^{p}>\alpha^p\rbrace} {|f|}^p \geqslant \alpha^p \lambda \left( \lbrace{|f|}^{p}>\alpha^p\rbrace \right) = \alpha^p \lambda \left( \lbrace|f|>\alpha\rbrace \right)
$$
or rearranging:
$$
\lambda \left( \lbrace|f|>\alpha\rbrace \right) \leqslant \frac{1}{\alpha^p} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} {|f|}^{p} < \infty 
$$
(this sometimes goes by the name of Chebyshev's inequality). However, functions in $L^{\infty}$ will not satisfy this property: simply take $f=1$, then $f\in L^{\infty}$ but for $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, $\lambda \left( \lbrace|f|>\alpha\rbrace \right) = \lambda \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right) = \infty$.